# Custom localStorage js function not running in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, local-storage

### What I'm trying to do:

Create my own storage API on top of localStorage so it is easier to use in my own code.

### Why?

So it has an API for my purposes and can be extended later.

### System:

Chrome Version: Version 22.0.1229.94 m

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ttback/kr88W/

### Error

The fiddle will trigger an error in Console:

#### TypeError: Property 'localStorageSave' of object # is not a function

This works in IE 8 and Firefox 16.0.1, so I am wondering if I'm missing something or is it a Chrome bug.

### Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JS function not working in Chrome</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var localStorage = localStorage || {};
localStorage.localStorageSave = function(){
    alert("SAVE");
};
localStorage.localStorageSave();
</script>
</head>
<body>

    
</body>

</html>​
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ? To extend localStorage ?

Comment: Fiddles are great, but please also include your code in the question so the question can stand on its own.

Comment: isnt localStorage a reserved word?

Comment: renaming localStorage to localStorage2 made it work fine, unless that isnt what you are trying to do...

Comment: `Storage` objects (like `localStorage`) have a special behavior that any member variable stored in it are converted to strings and saved persistently. This, your anonymous function is cast to a string and stored persistently.

Comment: so it looks like....the naming problem. I'll include the code in a min

Comment: You mean you didn't knew what localStorage is ? If so, yes, name differently your object.

Comment: If you didn't knw what localStorage was then what is the use of line `var localStorage = localStorage || {};`

Comment: I know what it is, but I suppose I should have done it in a custom namespace. I thought adding functions to it wouldn't have worked just like a normal javascript function, but it turned the content into string instead. This is a bad practice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do

```
localStorage.localStorageSave = function(){
    alert("SAVE");
};
```

you're doing the same as

```
localStorage["localStorageSave"] = function(){
    alert("SAVE");
};
```

or

```
localStorage.setItem("localStorageSave", (function(){
    alert("SAVE");
}).toString());
```

You're in fact not saving a function in localStorage, because [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage) saves only strings.

You can check it with

```
console.log(typeof(localStorage.localStorageSave));
```

You get `"string"`. This isn't a function and is normal.

Comment: awesome explaination. I was wondering why the assigned function is stored as string. How come it is working on other browsers?

Comment: perhaps other objects only allow setting a value to the storage with `[]` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining the why. I guess using the reserved word was the root of this issue. Though, why the code is working on other browsers is still a mystery.

Comment: setItem and the brace notation are documented. I guess other browser makers didn't think about the dot notation for localStorage.

Comment: The dot notation works just as well as brackets for `localStorage`. Here's what is actually happening: `var localStorage` creates a new `undefined` local variable that is hoisted to the top of the scope. Thus, when you do `var localStorage = localStorage || {}`, `localStorage` is set to the new object, because the local value of `localStorage` is undefined. Thus, it works in those browsers because you are not actually storing your function in the real `localStorage` -- you're storing it in a new local variable. This fails in Chrome because it doesn't allow `localStorage` to be overwritten.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
localStorage.__proto__.localStorageSave = function(){
    alert("SAVE");
};
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wphFJ/1/)**

Comment: Obviously hard call for me to make about which answer is best. Your answer also works. I am going with dystroy's one because he explained why it happened, which was very hard to understand for my knowledge. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: yeah i would have also gone with dystroy's  ans, He explained it splendidly :)

Answer (score 2):

You should not extend window.localStorage. Better way is:

```
var myNameSpace = {};

myNameSpace.localStorage = {

    save: function (name, object) {

        //save to localStorage
        window.localStorage.setItem(name, window.JSON.stringify(object));

    }

}

myNameSpace.localStorage.save('testObject', {test: true});
```